# How to Use the value in the java Annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, jvm

I want to define several annotations as following, how to archieve it?

```
@interface Annotation1 {
    String value();
    String type();
}

@Annotation1(value=`valueInAnnoatation2()`, type = 'batch')
@interface Annotation2 {
   String valueInAnnoatation2();
}
```

Anyone knows how to do this in jvm?

Comment: Jorn's answer is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what you want is annotate a class with `@Annotation2("value")`, then have the processor understand it as `@Annotation1("value", type = "batch")`.

You can't. Annotation values have to be compile time constants, so you can't refer to one annotation's value in another.

Instead, you have to do this in your annotation processor (either compile time or runtime).